# Why (Integer) 222 != (Integer) 222 in Java?

Tags: java, integer, equals, equality

It holds true for `(Integer) 1 == (Integer) 1`, which seems legitimate.

So why it's having excursion for  `(Integer) 222`'s equality?

Comment: Just don't use == "because it works for this case", you are comparing objects, so use equals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Integer` is a class. So to compare objects you need to use `equals` instead of `==`

What actually happens with shorter Integer is that if you get an `Integer` using the method `valueOf` you get always the same cached instance for values between -128 and 127. So in this case `==` works.

It doesn't work if you instead of using `valueOf` create a new instance explicitly with the operator `new`.

---

For To be more clear I write the current implementation of valueOf

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
    }
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: but it holds true for (Integer) 1 == (Integer) 1 ?

Comment: Check for the updated answer

Comment: Interesting -1 for a correct answer

Comment: I didn't downvote, but people also downvote for people answering questions that should not be answered - in this case because it is an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Yes but it is always a bad behaviour to downvote a correct answer. Better is to vote to close the question, not to downvote a correct answer.